Differences between terminal block designs
What are the differences in the terminal blocks used on both of these buck converters and how does the attaching mechanism for input/output wires differ? What are the comparative pros and cons between them?



Not a full answer, but a search term for you: the ones on that first module are what I would call barrier blocks.

The top ones look like larger (7.5mm pitch?) barrier blocks with (I think) a moving clamp plate.
The bottom ones look like 5mm or 5.08mm pitch screw terminal blocks with a spring clamp.
Current rating for the top one will be higher, and it will generally be nicer to use, and can probably accept a wider range of wire sizes.
Everything I can see on the bottom unit looks the same or a bit worse, so I would expect it to be cheaper.

The top looks like a barrier block for spade terminals, the bottom looks like a rising-cage terminal block for wire with or without a ferrule.
A good product would tell you the acceptable terminal/wire/ferrule sizes and, equally importantly, the torque values but these look suspiciously like Amazon/alibaba products so you might have to wing it.

"for spade terminals". Thank you for calling a spade a spade. Too many people today say "spade" when they mean a quick-connect disconnect. But originally the term spade has been for an open ring terminal, which is what fits in that barrier block.

The bottom one is not a rising cage type. There's just a thin spring leaf that the screw bears on directly. Cheap-a** terminal block. I have a bag of them right here, straight from buying them personally at the SEG market in Huaqiangbei. They come in 2's and 3's and you can dovetail them together to make whatever length is required.
